# Any CA Cert trusted by default on ubuntu?

Tags: security, certificates

I understand I can copy the CA cert to certain location and run script `update-ca-certificate` to import CA cert to the system.

But I'm curious is there a list of CAs that are trusted by default on this system?  Just like how it was done in the browser scenarios?

Answer (score -1):

Spend a few minutes to explore I found this question:
[Become a trusted Certificate Authority in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/713021/become-a-trusted-certificate-authority-in-ubuntu)

and its answer contains what I'm looking for, essentially:

```
cat /usr/share/doc/ca-certificates/README.Debian
```

### How certificates will be accepted into the ca-certificates package

- Get it included into Mozilla's trust store.
- File a bug against ca-certificates stating this fact.
  ....

And I can find the list here:
https://wiki.mozilla.org/CA:IncludedCAs