# What does "setting up" and "proccessing triggers" mean in apt-get?

Tags: apt, packaging

When apt-get is setting up a package or processing triggers for a package what actually happens in the background?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/27933/what-are-post-installation-triggers